# CocoPods error on installing flutter with bazel

Tags: ios, flutter, bazel

I'm trying to build an `ipa` file using bazel and flutter, then I have the following BUILD file:

```
genrule(
    name = "flutter_build_ios",
    srcs = glob(["ios/**","lib/**","assets/**", "pubspec.yaml"]),
    outs = ["mobile.ipa"],
    cmd_bash = "flutter build ipa --export-options-plist ios/Runner/ExportOptions.plist --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols && cp build/ios/ipa/mobile.ipa $@ && cp build/app/outputs/symbols $(@D)",
    tags = ["local"]
)
```

When I try to execute the bazel command: `@bazel build //:flutter_build_ios --verbose_failures` I got error:

```
(Could not create '/var/root/.cocoapods/repos', the CocoaPods repo cache directory.
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /var/root/.cocoapods)
You can try adding it manually in `/var/root/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I don't know why bazel is trying to use `/var/root` instead of `~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/`. I tried execute the same command in my terminal, without bazel: `flutter build ipa --export-options-plist ios/Runner/ExportOptions.plist --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols` and everything works fine.

I think I'm missing something about how bazel works under the hood.

**Solution:**
Genrule keeps only basic environment variables when executing `cmd` commands (https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#genrule-environment), and since `cocopods` rely on some environment variables, I have needed to set the following `export CP_HOME_DIR=/tmp/cocoapods-repo` before execute anything.

Comment: Haven't worked. Seems `repo-update` does not existe, the error: `Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options. `

Comment: Please run pod install --repo-update inside the project ios path

Comment: @KaushikChandru I updated my question with the solution.